# How to run maven tests in a specific order?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I have a maven project and several test classes.

I want to run these tests in a specific order with the plug-in surefire.

For example, I have:

- ClassTest1.java
- ClassTest2.java
- ClassTest3.java
- ClassTest4.java

I want to run the Class 1, then 2, then 3 and finally 4.

How can I specify this in the pom.xml?

Comment: Besides all the answers already given, you might also have a look at TestNG, which supports some test ordering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One workaround is to set the `runOrder` parameter to alphabetical and then rename your tests to have alphabetical order.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This isn't recommended, though - unit tests should be independent of each other. The execution order shouldn't matter.

Comment: And if i have set priority for each methods like priority=0, 1, 2. In that case it runs the classes randomly. Even though I have renamed the classes to TC_000, TC_001, TC_002 like this. And every classes - methods starts with priority=0 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `runOrder` parameter.

From the documentation:

> Defines the order the tests will be run in. Supported values are
>   "alphabetical", "reversealphabetical", "random", "hourly"
>   (alphabetical on even hours, reverse alphabetical on odd hours),
>   "failedfirst", "balanced" and "filesystem".

See the full description [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder).

Here is an example

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <configuration>
        <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How can I use this from command line?  
`mvn test -Drunorder=alphabetical  : is this correct?`

Comment: @biligunb No. It should be `mvn test -Dsurefire.runOrder=alphabetical` referring to the User Property at https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to define the order in testng.xml and then create profile via maven and run it. Here is a code sample you can try out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Selenium Automation" parallel="false">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="some.package.Class1"/>
            <class name="some.package.Class2"/>
            <class name="some.package.Class3"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And then in POM.xml you can create a profile as below and refer to the testNG.xml which you want to execute.

```
<profile>
    <id>any id</id>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin/>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JUnitCore to execute the tests in a specific order. Here is a basic implementation.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Class> testCases = new ArrayList<Class>();

    //Add test cases
    testCases.add(Class1.class);
    testCases.add(Class2.class);
    for (Class testCase : testCases)
           {
                runTestCase(testCase);
           }
}

private static void runTestCase(Class testCase)
{
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(testCase);
    for (Failure failure : result.getFailures())
    {
        System.out.println(failure.toString());
    }
}
```

Is there a reason you need them executed in a specific order? The tests should ideally not have dependencies on each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a testsuite class with junit and then use surefire to run this class instead, it will run with the order you give, for example:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 
import org.junit.runners.Suite; 
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses; 

@RunWith(Suite.class) 
@SuiteClasses({ 
Test1.class
Test2.class
Test3.class
Test4.class
}) 

public class TestSuite { 

}
```