# How can we control the ordering of the reporting of the tests in a testng report

Tags: selenium, testng

Is there any way by which I can control the ordering of the reports of the tests executed in a testng report.

Comment: What language are your tests written in?

Comment: What is the report? What exactly you are testing? Make your question more explicit

Comment: can you make your question more explicit, are you generating reports through testng.xml or are you talking about normal test reports?

Comment: Hello, @user1643723, I am using Java.

Comment: @Andersson - The report is a surefire report that I am generating.

Comment: @pArAs I am not generating it from testng.xml, rather I am using the Maven plugin report (surefire report)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run maven tests in a specific order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252705/how-to-run-maven-tests-in-a-specific-order)

Answer (score 1):

Use  `priority` in your test e.g. `@Test(priority=1)`

Comment: as I am using Maven plugin report (surefire report), and not TestNG report, so even setting the priority is not working.

Comment: as I am using Maven plugin report (surefire report), and not TestNG report, so even setting the priority is not working.